# Arithmetic ratios question

Tags: arithmetic

There are $850000$ users on an educational platform. On average, one user uses the platform $11$ times per month. There are two types of users: college and university students: the college ones use the platform $7$ times per month and the university one $13$ times per month. How many are college users?

I have tried to work the solution out by creating equations but I think I am missing something as I can't produce enough relations to work with.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question has been downvoted because you did not show what you tried to answer it yourself and where you got stuck. Please edit the question to show that. Then folks here will be glad to help you. (You may get an answer even if you don't do that, but you should anyway - particularly if you ask more questions in the future.)

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{x(7) + (850000-x)13}{850000} = 11,$ where $x$ is the number of college users.

Comment: Thanks a lot ab123!!

Comment: @Ilhan If this is a satisfactory answer you can accept it (the checkmark), You can upvote it too (the up arrow). That's the right way to say "thank you" - the comment is unnecessary. If there is more than one good answer you can upvote several (but can only accept one).